# async.waterfall never executes second function

Tags: javascript, async.js

Why does the second function here never get executed:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(waterfallCb) {
        console.log("step1");
        countDocuments(db,waterfallCb);
    }, function(waterfallCb) {
        console.log("Step2");
        insertDocument(db,waterfallCb);
    }], function(err,data){
    console.log("in waterfall callback");
    db.close();
});
```

Output:

```
step1
in waterfall callback
```

Why is the second function (which prints step 2) never getting called?

EDIT: Here is countDocuments:

```
var countDocuments = function(db,callback){
    var collection = db.collection(colname);
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Found %d records",docs.length);
        callback(docs);
    });
};
```

EDIT: InsertDocument:

```
var insertDocument = function(db, callback){
    var collection = db.collection(colname);
    collection.insertOne(sampleDoc, function(err,result){
        assert.equal(err, null);
        assert.equal(1, result.result.n);
        assert.equal(1, result.ops.length);
        console.log("inserted 1 document into the collection");
        callback(null, 'one');
    });
};
```

Comment: My guess: `countDocuments` isn't calling the first `waterfallCb`.

Comment: Are you using [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)? The first argument is the error object, which in your case if it's anything other than `null` might be telling async that you have an error and to not continue

Comment: Hah!  @JasonSperske you are right!

Comment: That is the fastest I have ever turned a comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you using [`caolan/async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall), the first argument is the error object, which in your case if it's anything other than null might be telling async that you have an error and to not continue.  Here is an example from the docs:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

Comment: That was fast. One more question: Now I'm getting "TypeError: object is not a function" on the callback line in insertDocument which looks like: callback(null);     -- why?

Comment: Can you add your `insertDocument` function to your question? or is the TypeError happening inside `function(waterfallCb) {console.log("Step2");insertDocument(null,db,waterfallCb);}`?

Comment: It tells me the error is happening on the last line of whatever the second function in the waterfall is. So for example, the last line (callback line) of insertDocument.

Comment: Ah, don't forget to update the argument signatures of your anonymous functions that you are passing to `async.waterfall()`

Comment: please can you elaborate?

Comment: UPDATE: NM - I lucked out in trying stuff. What an epic. Tx for your help.